# Can I apply the properties of big-O on f(n) in the case of T(n)=O(n^f(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Let's suppose that we have an algorithm with a complexity of the form T(n)=O[n^f(n)].
For example:
`T(n) = O[n^(n^2-n+1)]`.

Can I apply the properties of big-O on f(n) the same way as on T(n)?

I.e., Can I write:
`T(n) = O[n^(n^2)]` instead of `T(n) = O[n^(n^2-n+1)]`?

Comment: No. Say `f(n)=3`, then `f(n)=O(1)`, but `O(n^3)` is very different from `O(n^1)`.

Answer (score 4):

No, for example O(1)=O(2), but O(n^1) is a proper subset of O(n^2). By the way, it doesn't even work with addition or multiplication because the O-notation is not tight.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are counterexample for your case, under the following conditions you can replace `f(n)` with `g(n)` that `T(n) = O(n^f(n))` and `f(n) = O(g(n))`:

```
g(n) - f(n) > 0 for all n > 0
```

You can looking at your example for instance of this case. Hence, if the condition is hold, we can say `T(n) = O(n^g(n))`.

Also, your case is not true when `f(n) = Theta(g(n))`, as of @Mo B. example. By the way, based on the above condition, we can replace the `f(n)` with `g(n)` in `T(n) = O(n^f(n))`.